# Doing a join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to achieve a join where the select statement has multiple column that will reference the same name in a particular table, example:

```
SELECT
    sh.shift_number,
    sh.workplace_num,
    wp.workplace_name,
    sh.workplace_num2,
    sh.workplace_num3
FROM shifts AS sh
INNER JOIN workplace AS wk
    ON wp.workplace_num = wk.workplace_num
```

My problem is I'm able to get the name of the first workplace, how do i get the same for workplace2 or workplace three

```
Shift_number | workplace_Num | workplace_name | workplace_Num2 | workplace_Num3
4            | 2             | Teller         | 3              | 4
```

As you can see o Wk_placename(Teller) displays the name of wk_placeNum(2) I'd like to be able to show the names of Wk_placeNum2 and Wk_placeNum3 they all take the workplace name from the joined workplace table!!

I'm restricted from uploading a picture, hopefully the illustration paints a picture!!

Comment: Please update your question and show us the output you are currently getting, along with what your want the output to be.  Sample data would also be helpful.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Tried my best, please check if you can assist

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  my current join only allows me to much the workplace name to a single workplace number, yet i have two other workplace numbers which id like to view there respective workplace names i do not knw how to improve my statement so i can alse get the workplace names for the remaining two workplace numbers

Comment: Join with the same table once more, just give it another alias.

Comment: @Jens Awesome thanks, it worked!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join multiple times to the *workplace* table. Note that as you did not specified whether the fields *workplace_num2* and *workplace_num3* are nullable, I assumed these are so used *LEFT JOIN*. You should use *INNER JOIN* if these are not nullable:

```
SELECT
    sh.shift_number,
    sh.workplace_num,
    wp.workplace_name,
    sh.workplace_num2,
    wp2.workplace_name as workplace_name2,
    sh.workplace_num3
    wp3.workplace_name as workplace_name3,
FROM shifts AS sh
INNER JOIN workplace AS wp
    ON sh.workplace_num = wp.workplace_num
LEFT JOIN workplace AS wp2
    ON sh.workplace_num2 = wp2.workplace_num
LEFT JOIN workplace AS wp3
    ON sh.workplace_num3 = wp3.workplace_num
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    sh.shift_number,
    sh.workplace_num,
    wk.workplace_name,
    wk2.workplace_name,
    wk3.workplace_name
FROM shifts AS sh
INNER JOIN workplace AS wk
    ON sh.workplace_num = wk.workplace_num
INNER JOIN workplace AS wk2
    ON sh.workplace_num2 = wk2.workplace_num
INNER JOIN workplace AS wk3
    ON sh.workplace_num3 = wk3.workplace_num
```